# How to replace GU5.3 track light bulb?

Tags: electrical

Can anyone show how to replace this type of track light bulb please?

[image]

Comment: A quick image search for "GU5.3 bulb" shows that they have 2 straight pins at the end. This indicates to me that they pull straight out. I'd suggest holding the fixture and pulling the bulb. Have you tried that?

Comment: Are you sure those are GU5.3 and not GU10? GU5.3 will just pull out, but GU10 needs to be twisted. New bulbs normally come with a suction cup to help.

Comment: Yes, it is GU5.3 20 Watt, I can't stick my figure in there to turn it. I probably stick the tape and twist again to see what happen.